# Java socket connection time out in Android Implementation

Tags: android, sockets, socketexception

I'm writing a simple android code for file transfer over Java sockets. First of all, I hard coded my file path in my server implementation to check if the files are received successfully at client side or not. It worked fine. Then I created a simple file browser as a separate Java class so that user could browse through the files and select them as well. For this purpose, I created a simple intent to launch the file browser class (the intent is fired just after socket initialization). My problem starts from here.
Before this file browser thing, my app was working fine (with pre-defined set of files). But now, I'm getting socket closed exception every time I run the app. It doesn't even reach the intent firing stage. Please help me. I'm mostly self taught and still learning Android programming. Here are my code snippets:

Server:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ArrayList<File> fileArray = new ArrayList<File>();
ArrayList<String> filepathNameArray = new ArrayList<String>();
Socket socket = null;
ServerSocket serversocket = null;
int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Thread trd = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            initializeServer();
            Intent launchFileManager = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    FileChooserActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(launchFileManager, REQUEST_CODE);
            if (!fileArray.isEmpty()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.size(); i++)
                    copyFile(fileArray.get(i), fileArray.get(i).getName());
            }
        }
    });
    trd.start();
}
private void initializeServer() {
    try {
        serversocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Listen failed", "Listening to port 4444 failed");
    }
    try {
        socket = serversocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Binding Failed", "Couldn't accept socket connection");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            filepathNameArray = data.getExtras().getStringArrayList("key");// file URI received
            for(int f=0;f<filepathNameArray.size();f++){
                fileArray.add(new File(filepathNameArray.get(f))); //create file array
            }
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast cancelToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Nothing selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            cancelToast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

FileChooser returning Intent Result:

```
selectionDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // selFilePathList is the file path list of selected files
            Intent returnIntent=new Intent();
            returnIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("key", selFilePathList);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Client:

```
public class Receiver {
static Socket socket = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    InetAddress serverIP;
    try {
        serverIP = InetAddress.getByName("10.87.3.91");
        socket = new Socket(serverIP, 4444);
        if (socket != null) {
            System.out.println("Connection established!!");
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                receiveDOS();
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I've also added necessary manifest permission:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Console output:

```
03-24 22:26:02.452: W/System.err(22973): java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
03-24 22:26:02.452: W/System.err(22973):    at libcore.io.Posix.accept(Native Method)
03-24 22:26:02.452: W/System.err(22973):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:55)
03-24 22:26:02.452: W/System.err(22973):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:98)
03-24 22:26:02.452: W/System.err(22973):    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:202)
03-24 22:26:02.452: W/System.err(22973):    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:127)
03-24 22:26:02.452: W/System.err(22973):    at com.example.zztest.MainActivity.initializeServer(MainActivity.java:57)
03-24 22:26:02.452: W/System.err(22973):    at com.example.zztest.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:49)
03-24 22:26:02.452: W/System.err(22973):    at com.example.zztest.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:36)
03-24 22:26:02.462: W/System.err(22973):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-24 22:26:02.462: D/Binding Failed(22973): Couldn't accept socket connection
```

Any idea or suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The result of new Socket() cannot be null, so testing it is pointless. It seems a bit strange to initialize the server by calling accept(). 'Socket closed' means *you* closed the socket, although I don't see how that can happen in this code unless initializeServer() can get called twice.

Comment: Is it something to do with the client side loop where I've called receiveDOS() method?

Comment: You closed the ServerSocket, in the server code. Is this the  real code?